# React: Encapsule selection text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need help with something.
In my application I have the following case:

`<p>`

`<strong> Lorem ipsum </strong> is simply dummy text from the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`

`</p>`

When I select the text, I need it to be encapsulated in a short time, but without losing any labels. by means, for example:

Suppose you selected the text `"ipsum is simply"`, if you look, in the middle is the closing tag of strong, then you would really be selecting the following: `"ipsum </strong> is simply"`
I need that with this selection by means of javascript the text is encapsulated only within the span and something like this remains:

`<p>`

`<strong> Lorem <span>ipsum</span> </strong> <span> is simply </span> dummy text from the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry`

`</p>`

As you can see, within `<strong>`, the text that was inside it and was selected, it is inside a  tag and outside the `<strong>` there is another  of the text that was selected.
Something else is that if there are several paragraphs and the text is selected between them, the paragraphs are preserved, but even so the selected text is encapsulated within a `<span>`, something like this:

`<p> Lorem ipsum, absolem dut </p>`

`<p> Amen ipsum pain </p>`

Suppose you select the following: `"absolem dut Amen pain"`
`"absolem dut"` belongs to one paragraph and "Amen pain" to the other, this should give a result like this:

````` <p> Lorem ipsum, <span> absolem dut </span> </p>```` `````

Amen pain  ipsum ```

I already tried using getContains from the window's getSelection property and it doesn't work, this generates a new paragraph. If anyone knows how to do this or has an idea of ​​how to do it using the JS nodes or if the questions have any instructions, I would really appreciate it

I find a vanilla solution, because this function is on React

Comment: You would like your selection to be put into spans, inside of their parent?

Comment: Yes men! I need this!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after much time with some trial and error I believe I have created something that solves what you were requesting. If not, please let me know as soon as possible. Before the code a brief explanation and what needs to be fixed for production use.

### Optimizations Required

- Change to edit in Document Fragment rather than Range then replace with one operation

  - Essentially to do this you will need to convert the replace live to take replace the node or even better pull the entire edited chunk into a fragment and run this on an object rather than on the DOM tree. However, I will leave that to you
  - [Performance of Range](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2017/mutating-web-content-using-dom-ranges/)
  - [Rationale for Document Fragment](https://medium.com/@maddydeep28/dom-creation-and-manipulation-tips-and-tricks-df4707ede27c)
- Figure out a fully multiplatform solution, while this worked on firefox on desktop I cannot guarantee that for all platforms, however, the support for the Range and Selection Web APIs is quite covered, especially for the functions used here.

  - [Range MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)
  - [Selection MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
- If this is being utilized inside React you may want to essentially track selected content with state (hooks or classes, I prefer hooks). Essentially hold an array with refs (maybe react refs, but probably not, please review [React Ref Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) if you have any questions) instead, perhaps an anchor within the component itself that can be referenced with render props or something along those lines should be used instead? I'm not sure, but perhaps that will help.

### Code

First off, if you would like to see a live version please visit [this](https://jsbin.com/facimariqe/5/edit?html,console,output) JSBin. I hope there are enough comments here to explain what is going on, I tried to explain my-self and kept console sorta clean for this version. Here is TL;DR; of the execution:

1. Add an Event Listener for `selectstart` on the document object (Please limit this to containers for which this will be utilized, please)
2. On even fired add an Event Listener for `mouseup` (this is where multiplatform breaks a bit :/)
3. If Ctrl key held down (this may need some tweaking too :/) return null and continue listening for mouseup, if not, then:

   1. Set up counter and begin execution of `do...while(count < [select].rangeCount)`
   2. An error **will be thrown** if the selection crosses into other elements, if no error is thrown then utilize `[range].surroundWith([Node]);`
   3. If the error is thrown then the next crawler will crawl through both elements and execution the HTML mutator function `replaceLive` to change the HTML, please read my warning in the comments.
   4. If no more elements to crawl through then remove the `mouseup` Event Listener (Good Practice, plus rogue listeners are never fun...)
4. Listen for the next selection

```js
function remove(arr) {
  for(const ele of arr) {
    ele.replaceWith(ele.innerText);
  }
}

function mouseUP (e) {
  // Maybe have to handle this differently, just easier for now :/
  if (e.ctrlKey === true) {return;}

  let selectedText = document.querySelectorAll(".selected-text");

  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    remove(selectedText);
  }

  let selection = document.getSelection();
  //console.log(selection.anchorNode);
  let count = 0;
  do {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(count);
    try {
      range.surroundContents(span);
      span.classList.add("selected-text");
    } catch (e) {
      //console.log(e);

      // Will extract HTML from selection into div, sadly does not 
      // include the overall parent might be able to write some 
      // logic to that for you via startContainer and limit to text
      // HTML element such as: p, span, etc. (textarea and input do
      // not support selection according to mdn, in firefox!)
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.append(range.cloneContents());

      // Ensuring that end will not be skipped, at-least I hope
      // May need another check to verify next was not a text node
      // Although, I think this can be safely assumed.
      if (!range.endContainer instanceof HTMLElement) {
        range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer);
      }

      // To track inside of extracted HTML?
      let innerCount = 0;

      // Will crawl through range
      while (range.startContainer !== range.endContainer) {
        let tmp = range.startContainer;
        // To ignore the Nodes and only look at HTML Elements
        if (!(tmp instanceof HTMLElement)) {
          range.setStartAfter(tmp);
          continue;
        }
        //console.log(tmp.tagName);

        /**
         * Replace Live
         * 
         * Will take in a string and regex match it to the target
         * HTMLElement's innerHTML then add span tag with content
         * ToSsurround as child. Finally, setting innerHTML of child
         * to the newly created DOMString.
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} targetNode - Target to surround content inside of
         * @param {String} contentToSurround - New Inner HTML for node
         */
        function replaceLive (targetElement, newHTML) {
          let origHTML = targetElement.innerHTML;

          // If you wanted to add a css class or something do it here :)
          origHTML = origHTML.replace(newHTML, `<span class="selected-text">${newHTML}</span>`);
          console.log(origHTML);
          // Warning this will cause a repaint for each execution!
          // Extract into Document and replace the whole node if
          // possible. For now this was faster, but please convert
          // to use fragment to keep off of DOM Tree in production!
          targetElement.innerHTML = origHTML;
        }

        try {
          const htmlContent = div.querySelector(tmp.tagName).innerHTML;
          replaceLive(tmp, htmlContent)               
        } catch (e) {
          //console.log(div);
          const node = div.childNodes.item(innerCount);
          if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
            replaceLive(tmp, node.innerHTML);
          } else if (node instanceof Node) {
            replaceLive(tmp, node.nodeValue);
          } else {
            throw TypeError("Invalid node passed!");
          }
        }
        range.setStartAfter(tmp);
        innerCount++;
      }
    }
    count++;
  } while (count < selection.rangeCount);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUP); // Clean up listener
}

// This failed inside jsbin
//document.addEventListener('select', e => console.log(e));

document.addEventListener('selectstart', () => {
  /* 
    May have to add a check for platform to know if pointer events are
    required instead. I tested on mobile, pointer events seemed spotty
    so using mouse events only for now.
  */
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUP);
});
```

Comment: Yes! This function is good, but the last spans not disappear when I select again other text

Comment: So you need to delete the span if one is present or delete last selection entirely?

Comment: Yes man, because after this function the user can click a button and add a comment of his selection

Comment: Okay I will work on it later tonight I imagine you could just store each span created into an array called ref and simply iterate through removing surrounding spans then processing next call.

Comment: Yes, the objective is convert the result to string and pass this value to other function, this I know how to make, but this encapsulation is my biggest obstacle

Comment: Sorry it took so long, life came in the way. I utilized classes and then queried for all selectors giving you a list of selection and a way to query from anything. As well as easily undoing changes by using the built in replace with and taking advantage of text type nodes.